# Auto Populate the Opportunity Owner name into custom text field

Tags: salesforce, force.com, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to auto populate the Opportunity Owner name in to custom field(Manger) on the same page. But when i am trying it's getting only Id but not Owner Name. This logic i am implementing using Flow in the process builder. Can some one help on this.
In the flow i am using 'Record Lookup'(getting OwnerId and passing to Temp variable), Record Update(Assigning the temp variable to Custom field). But not luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would not want the Id. I personally would use the Owner field as a basis and just create a formula field called `Manager` with this formula: `Owner.Name`

If you still insist on getting the Owner Name from the flow, you would have to do a SOQL Select in the flow to search and save the Name first.